# Язык C, malloc() и NULL

Tags: c, windows, null, malloc

Хотел бы обсудить, что делать, если **malloc()** вернул **NULL**.

Ясное дело, что если ведется разработка библиотеки или какого-либо "кирпичика", который будет использоваться неизвестно в каких условиях, то вызов **abort()** совершенно неприемлем.

Например, если пишется загрузчик ресурсов из файла в оперативную память, то лучше бы сказать "извини, памяти нет", чем внезапно упасть неизвестно по какой причине.

1) От людей, которые пишут под **Linux**, слышал, что они не проверяют результат вызова **malloc()**, обосновывая это тем, что **malloc()** запросто может вернуть не **NULL**, а при попытке обращения к памяти через такой указатель все рухнет. Ибо память изначально выделяется в виртуальной области, и такая память не связывается с реальной до тех пор, пока к ней не произойдет обращение.

В Windows 10/8/7/Em/CE тоже так?

2) Если память выделяется маленькими порциями, то может произойти такое, что при неудачном **malloc()** мы хотим сделать **printf()**, не говоря уже про **fopen() + fwrite()**, а памяти нет, и все совсем падает. Это реально?

3) Довольно долго думал над тем, как защитить программу, которая крутится на ПЛК, обеспечивая передачу телеметрии. Сам объект находится далеко - "три для ехать, а потом еще на вертолете с пересадками". В общем, классический пример промышленных систем.

Приложение многопоточное. Одни потоки отправляют/получают данные, другие устанавливают соединение по TCP, третьи - ведут файлы журналов. Много библиотек, часто - закрытых в dll.

В итоге пришел к выводу, что единственное адекватное решение, если **malloc()** где-то вернул **NULL**, - это вызов **abort()**, с последующей скорой перезагрузкой отдельным модулем, который определил, что наше приложение перестало "теребить" какой-то сигнализатор. Защита журналов в этом случае делается тривиальным способом - при каждом старте процесса создается новый журнал. Таким образом, старые журналы могут иметь в конце какой-то недописанный "хвост", но это нестрашно.

Ни разовое аллоцирование, ни "умный" управляющий памятью, - не дают гарантий, а лишь приводят к сингулярному разрастанию возможных неопределенных поведений.

4) Я так понимаю, на исчерпывающем большинстве промышленных устройств сторожевой таймер предусмотрен как раз из-за того, что существуют вот такие неразрешимые программным путем проблемы, как неудачный **malloc()** и исчерпание памяти?

Comment: malloc работает в две фазы, если обе отработали - то - негде взять свободную память. Действительно негде. Механизм "сигнализации" не должен содержать malloc. Я бы сказал так, что б malloc начал снова работать - нужно сделать free. Если есть модули которые могут сделать free - то можно сделав free, снова сделать malloc, а если нет - то всё - пат и аварийный выход.

Comment: Я думаю, нужно изначально понимать на какое колличество памяти вы затачиваете программу, и... предусматривать сброс каких-то данных на диск (правда дисковая память тоже может стать ограниченой), как вариант - возможно... использовать субд для хранение каких-то данных (вместо ручного распределения память/диск).

Comment: nick_n_a, не все так просто. malloc() вполне может зарезервировать память, для которой мы вызвали free(). На неопределенное время. Я уже молчу про то, что происходит в ядре ОС при выделении/освобождении памяти. Это довольно сложный процесс. Начиная от виртуальной памяти и зарезервированной, заканчивая поведением MMU.

Comment: Можно перетереть системный malloc, и самому реализовать выделение памяти. Главное определится с моделью памяти. Я считаю что хорошая модель - пулы. Есть несколько моделей памяти... и в зависимости от модели - будет тот или иной результат.

Comment: Даже если так и сделать, то как действовать, если в N-ном потоке процесса посреди сложной сетевой логики мы не смогли выделить память для промежуточного буфера?

Comment: Надо продумать модель памяти так, что бы вероятность такого события была минимальна. Протестировать на предмет утечек. Можно добавить поведение - например использовать Lock/Unlock. Там где важно что б память была - там использовать статический массив, или заранее выделеную память. Может сегментировать память и сделать сегменты приоритетными.

Comment: Так все и сделано, но это лишь уменьшает вероятность неудачного выделения памяти. Ситуации нехватки памяти в моей практике еще не было, потому что заранее вычисляются максимальные размеры очередей и буферов, но однажды malloc() вполне может вернуть NULL. И это может быть вызвано не ошибкой в программе, а тем, что какой-то другой процесс выжрал всю память.

Comment: Есть детерминированое(определённое) поведение, есть недетерминированое. Делайте определённое поведение, и отказывайте пользователю в неопределённом поведении - тогда 100% будет работать. Т.е. для работы вашей программы нужно 100Мб, вы можете обрабатывать пакеты по 1Мб - при старте резервируете 100Мб - и пожайлуста - работайте. Пользователю запрещаете подбрасывать файлы/пакеты свыше 1Мб. Если 100Мб нету - так и пишите - не хватает памяти- и не запускаете программу.Если же вы неможете определить поведение вашей программы-расчитать сколько вам нужно оперативки - то доверяете это OC и не жалуйтесь

Comment: Смотрим [brk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html)  и разбирается как работает :)

Comment: Любая библиотека должна уметь сообщить об ошибке. Ещё можно передать библиотеке свой API (массив указателей на функции, где будет и функция выделения), и выделять самостоятельно, с проверкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`malloc` всегда должет возвращать адрес, если malloc вернул `null` тогда это аварийная ситуация. Вы можете 1) Прекратить работу всей программы. 2) Вы можете прекратить работу "процесса" (не процесса как Process, а класса, библиотеки, функции или набора функций, например процесс компрессии данных), который не может завершить свою работу, освободить память занимаемую этим "процессом". Тут я солидарен с **alexolut**

Надо не забывать что у программы есть детерминированое - определённое поведение, и недетерминированое. Нужно стремится делать детерминированое поведение. В программе желательно до начала процесса (а не вовремя)  опеределить сколько нужно на процесс памяти, и не начинать процесс (или работу программы) если его не возможно выполнить. Нужно ограничивать аппетиты пользователя, если вам вместо 100Мб прислали 10Gb, то сообщить что файлы/потоки свыше 2Gb ваша программа не обрабатывает (условно, для примера). Нужно определить заранее на какие обьёмы вы хотите расщитывать, и проверять есть ли они (обьемы) в наличии. Если вы резервируете память столько незнаю сколько - то для небольших программ будет всё ок, а для больших - может закончится нехваткой памяти. Т.е. невозможно сделать `malloc` столько незнаю cколько.

В ответственных за скорость местах лучше использовать пулы памяти. Недостаток пулов - часть "неиспользуемой" памяти просто лежит.

Нужно соблюдать несколько правил... и тогда у вас память не закончится неожиданно.

- резервировать в ответственных местах память заранеее
- ограничивать глубину рекурсии в рекурсивных функциях (хвостовая рекурсия - отдельный случай)
- соблюдать порядок `malloc` и `free`. Желательно разделять память для долгого использования и для кратковременного. Сколько зарезервировано паралельными процессами. Проверять наличие утечки памяти (когда `malloc` больше чем `free`, но для этого нужно знать какое число, разница колличества вызовов malloc/free должна быть, и для этого нужно знать сколько памяти долгого использования зарезервировано).
- делать пулы, или массивы памяти, для возможности освободить память по завершению "процесса" которую будет использовать конкретный процесс (действие) (упростит освобожнение).
- память может закончится в двух случаях  а) неправильно построеная "модель памяти" (неопределённое поведение программы которое не предусмотрено) б) пользователь использует компьютер с реально маленьким размером оперативки и файлом подкачки. Второй случай редкий, но проверить его на старте стоит.

Ещё хочу заметить, что ОС уровня "приложение" оперирует виртуальной памятью, поэтому может такое быть, что ваше приложение занимает меньше памяти чем вы резервировали. Тут [Язык C, глобальные массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/844846/%d0%af%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-c-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b/844891) часный случай когда реально приложение занимает меньше памяти, чем виртуально.

Если для вас важна стабильность - резервируйте при запуске нужное количество памяти - и проблемы с `malloc` у вас не будет. Ведь главный вопрос не в том хватает памяти или не хватает, а в том - сколько вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. А тот пример, что вы привели, **Язык C, глобальные массивы**, это тоже мой вопрос)

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно подготовиться к обработке исчерпания памяти, то первым делом стоит обеспечить (зарезервировать) уже некоторый объём памяти для этих нужд. И всю обработку производить, опираясь на эти, заранее выделенные, объёмы.

Когда память закончилась - это значит, что что-то пошло не так, что-то что мы заранее не учли. Ведь в нормальной ситуации устройство должно обычно обеспечивать режим работы 24/7. Поэтому когда память вдруг неожиданно кончилась, самое правильное, что здесь можно сделать, это залогировать проблемную ситуацию и перезапуститься (упомянутый вами сторожевой таймер как раз для этих целей). А вот для логирования как раз будет полезен заранее предопределённый объем память. Работать с ним можно по-разному: либо непосредственно ссылаться на эту память, либо выполнить для неё `free` и рассчитывать, что последующие `malloc`, необходимые для корректной обработки аномальной ситуации, отработают корректно, т.е. предоставят недавно освобождённую память.

Comment: Я бы не делал free, а работал с имеющейся памятью. После free эту память может забрать соседний поток

Answer (score 1):

Если `malloc` возвращает NULL, то обращение к такому указателю в коде является неопределенным поведением, ожидание *любого* конкретного поведения ошибочно. Ну а обрабатывать стоит единообразно - если не знаете, как отреагировать на ошибку на месте, передавайте ее компетентному коду возвращая код ошибки / вызывая функцию обратного вызова или посредством другого механизма.

Comment: О неопределенном поведении мне известно. Проблема в том, что я не вижу вариантов, как можно обработать malloc() == NULL, кроме как сделать abort(). Например, функция одного из десятков потоков должна сформировать пакет с телеметрией, но не может, потому что под какой-то буфер пакета не удалось выделить память. Мы не можем вечно пытаться сформировать пакет, мы не можем сохранить текущие пакеты, так же мы не в состоянии синхронизировать множество потоков в этой ситуации. И любой такт промедления в такой ситуации - это рекурсивное вываливание NULL в различных частях программы.

Comment: @Максим А вы делегируйте обработку ошибки компетентному коду. Ошибки редко можно обработать не месте, обычно какие-то осмысленные действия возможно предпринять только в другом месте. Вот не удалось сформировать пакет мало памяти - хз что делать на месте, передаете выше в менеджер телеметрии - не удалось отправить кусок телеметрии мало памяти - хз что делать на месте, передаете выше в менеджер подсистем - отправка телеметрии не работает мало памяти - вот тут знаем что делать: флашим все файлы, освобождаем буфера и возобновляем телеметрию.

Comment: @Максим `abort` имеет смысл вызывать только в ситуации, когда обработка ошибки где-то еще *невозможна*, обычно это подразумевает, что программа находится в несогласованном состоянии

Comment: Окей, допустим, мы профлашили файлы. Но мы не можем освободить буфера, потому что в них находится информация, ради которой вся эта ерунда и существует. Для того, чтобы освободить буфера, - нам нужно закончить формировать пакет и затем его отправить. Мы не можем закончить формировать пакет. Ситуация безвыходная.

Comment: @Максим Ок, но обработка возвращения NULL все равно сводится к делегированию обработки ошибки коду, который компетентен заключить, что ситуация безвыходная. Формирователь пакетов телеметрии не компетентен делать такие заключения, как и менеджер телеметрии. Причем формирователь пакетов телеметрии ничего не знает о существовании каких-то менеджеров и их компетенциях, а менеджер телеметрии ничего не знает о менеджере подсистем и его компетенции. Они (точнее программист их пишущий) знает только, что он не знает, как обработать такую ошибку на этом уровне. И поэтому он делегирует обработку ошибки.